# Browser displaying blank page when I run my code

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

This is probably a very silly question but when I try to run my code in Notepad++ on either browser such as Chrome and IE. It's not showing. I have carefully looked at the code to see if i'm missing anything but I can't seem to figure out what.

I recently asked a question about help on my code and it got fixed, it was working when I ran the "Run code snippet" thingy but when I copied the code to my Notepad++, it's not working. This is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gamescript.js">
</head>

<body>
<p id ="door"> Which door do you wish to enter? Door 1 or Door 2? </p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<!---- Question 1 ---->
<p id ="choice1">Behind Door 1 is an empty room. Whilst searching the room for clues, you see a hidden passageway. Do you wish to enter the passageway or continue searching?</p>

<div id="question2">
<input id="myInput2" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction2()">Enter</button>
</div>


<!---- Boss ---->
<div id="question3">
<h1>Fight the Monster!</h1>

<p id="mspace"></p>

<div id="game">

  <button id="fight">Fight</button>
  <button id="run">Run</button>

</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

.

```
document.getElementById("choice1").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("question2").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("question3").style.visibility = "hidden";

function myFunction(){
    var door = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    if (door == "Door 1" || door == "door 1"){
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered " + door;
        document.getElementById("choice1").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("question2").style.visibility = "visible";
    }else if (door == "Door 2" || door == "door 2"){
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You have entered " + door;
        document.getElementById("choice1").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("question2").style.visibility = "visible";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("door").innerHTML = "You must enter a door!"
    }
}

function myFunction2(){
    var choice1 = document.getElementById("myInput2").value;
    if (choice1 == "enter passageway" || choice1 == "passageway"){
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "You entered the " + choice1;
        document.getElementById("question3").style.visibility = "visible";
     }else if (choice1 == "continue searching"){
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "You " + choice1; 
        document.getElementById("question3").style.visibility = "visible";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = "You must choose an option!"
    }
}

// JS for BOSS level
// starting variable for the boss
var stamina = 10;

// starting message
var msg = "A huge, threatening monster wants to fight you! What do you do?";
// run a function that is below
document.getElementById("mspace").innerHTML = msg;

// click a button to execute a function
// NOTE: no parentheses after the function name in these cases
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("fight").onclick = fightResponse;
    document.getElementById("run").onclick = runResponse;
}

function runResponse() {
  if (stamina > 8) {
    msg = "The monster swings his long arm and -- GAME OVER!";
    hideButtons();
  } else if (stamina > 3) {
    msg = "Well, that's one way to end a fight ...";
    hideButtons();
  } else {
    msg = "Keep fighting! The monster is almost dead!";
  }
  writeMessage();
}

function fightResponse() {
  if (stamina > 8) {
    msg = "The monster is strong! It resists your attack!";
  } else if (stamina > 5) {
    msg = "With a loud screech, the monster stands firm.";
  } else if (stamina > 3) {
    msg = "Your attack seems to be having an effect! The monster stumbles!";
  } else if (stamina > 0) {
    msg = "This monster is about to fall! It staggers and reels!";
  } else {
    msg = "With a final swing! The monster has been defeated! You have triumphed!";
    hideButtons();
  }
  // create new random number from 0 to 5
  var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  // subtract it from stamina
  stamina -= damage;
  writeMessage();
}

function hideButtons() {
  // changes the class on the div - see the CSS pane 
  document.getElementById("game").className = "hideThis";
}

function writeMessage() {
  document.getElementById("mspace").innerHTML = msg;
}
```

I tried using the F12 developer tool but no errors are showing. I don't know why it's not working on Notepad++. All help is always appreciated and thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a `</script>` so this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gamescript.js" >
```

becomes this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gamescript.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Omg, how did i miss that! thank you! the code isn't working like it did on the "run code snippet" but thank you anyway

Comment: I copied your code into a text file and it displayed just fine in the browser. Are you still getting a blank screen?

Comment: It's working now but when I use the F12 tool. It's saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" but it works in the code snippet of stack overflow. I don't understand

Comment: The "Fight the monster" part is not wokring

Comment: Oh, I see now. You're using the id of a <p> which is null. What you need to do is have an event on the "Enter" button that grabs the value of the textbox

Comment: I'm learning how to code and not that great at it as of yet. I'm learning, I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: I'm doing like a story based game where there are questions and you have to type in a choice...at the end, you enter into a Boss room...My knowledge in coding isn't the best

Comment: Try this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events_onsubmit and this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp